# PHP condição para nao exibir imagem quando não existe

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, imagem

O meu problema é o seguinte.tenho uma tabela com varias imagens de produtos, mas nem em todos os produtos eu tenho 5imagens(total de colunas da BD).
o que pretendia era "anular" a linha de html quando a imagem nao existe. tentei este código

```
<?php
 if (!empty($imagem3)) {
 ?>
  <td class="coluna_foto"><img src="<?php echo $imagem3; ?>" width="75" height="75" ></td>
  <?php }else{
  return false;
} 
?>
```

Acontece que a linha de html esta sempre fora do php e portanto ele fica sempre com o link e portanto quando nao tem foto aparece sempre o icon a "dizer" que nao existe foto... 
Alguem tem uma sugestão para resolver

Comment: Qual o seu valor padrão da coluna de imagens no BD?

Comment: A imagem está dentro do BD, ou são arquivos e o BD aponta pra eles? E pra quê o return false? Não seria só tirar a parte do else?

Comment: @Bacco, o que eu tenho dentro da bd é nome da imagem. esta avariavel "$imagem3" tem o caminho  e esta a funcionar.

Comment: @TiagoP.C o valor padrao é "NULL"

Comment: o problema é que ele escreve sempre a tag img e portanto aparece sempre aquela cruzinha a indicar que nao tem imagem!

Comment: @JoaquimRibeiro as respostas abaixo provavelmente devem resolver o problema, mas se não for o suficiente, dê um jeito do nome da imagem sair escrito na página tambem como teste, pode ser que esteja vindo algum valor indevido.

Comment: Primeiro, você não precisa colocar o nó lógico quando retorna vazio (`else { /* faz nada */}`. Depois, dá um `var_dump` na variável e vê o que aparece quando ela tá "vazia". Pode ser que seja `NULL`, por exemplo, aí você teria que acrescentar `&& !is_null ($imagem3) === FALSE`

Answer (score 3):

Coloca sua image no echo para escrever na pagina, assim mantem tudo no server-side.

```
<?php
 if (!empty($imagem3)) {
    echo("<td><img src='". $imagem3 ."'></td>")
 }
?>
```

Isso resolve seu problema?

Comment: Só pra comentar, tudo é server-side, e dá na mesma que "entrar e sair" do HTML (o PHP dá praticamente um echo implícito quando você usa `?>`). Agora, que manter um padrão mais limpo é melhor, é. Só que se for pra escrever 30 linhas de html, o echo fica até mais feio. PS: semana que vem vou tomar um café com o Markinho, e já vou aproveitar pra [pedir os seus déilão de volta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/34573/rboschini?tab=profile). De qualquer forma, só de tirar o false, já deve ajudar o autor, então +1.

Comment: Monta essa listagem por ajax, ou retorna um array JS e monta isso dinamico, com efeitos bacaninhas para o usuario ficar feliz. :D

Comment: nao funcionou. o link continua la e desformatou todo o resto da pagina!

Comment: @JoaquimRibeiro E ta linkando pra onde?

Comment: na base de dados como as restantes. e tenho as variaveis $imagem1,$imagem2 e $imagem3. na ultima deixei vazio o campo na base de dados para caso nao tenha 3 imagens para cada artigo

Comment: @JoaquimRibeiro Sim, mas no HTML quebrado o link da imagem aparece como? (veja no código fonte)

Comment: <img width="75" height="75" src="fotografias/">
é isto que aparece @Bacco

Comment: @JoaquimRibeiro E de onde vem esse "fotografias"? Provavelmente é ele que está no lugar errado do seu código. Devia ser `<img src="fotografias/<?php echo $imagem3; ?> ` mas esse fotografias deve estar sendo posto no lugar errado do php e nunca vai dar empty.

Comment: alias, nesse solução do @RBoschini dá o seguinte erro: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\dtcr\consuta_teste.php on line 68

Comment: @JoaquimRibeiro isso é só a falta de ";" depois do echo. Mas veja o que eu falei, pq provavelmente o erro é esse. Como você nao postou o código que pega as coisas do BD, nao dá pra ter certeza.

Answer (score 2):

Não tenho certeza se no seu caso a imagem3 está retornando nula ou vazia, mas tente este código.

assim caso queira que apareça uma imagem padrão caso não tenha no banco de dados.

```
<?php 
     $link_da_imagem = ($imagem3 == "fotografias/" ? "/caminho/para/imagem/vazia.jpg" : $imagem3); 
?>
<img src="<?php echo $link_da_imagem; ?>" width="75" height="75">
```

assim caso queira que não apareça nada:

```
<?php 
     if ($imagem3 != "fotografias/") { 
?>
        <img src="<?php echo $imagem3; ?>" width="75" height="75">
<?php 
     } 
?>
```

Comment: Acho legal o _placeholder_ como alternativa. Se você formatar um pouco melhor o código, acho que fica mais fácil o pessoal entender e votar.

Comment: identado para melhor visualização.

Comment: essa foi a forma que tentei. mas como a tag img esta fora do php, automaticamente ele mostra uma cruzinha indicando que falta a imagem. se nao arranjar melhor opção, vou criar uma foto vazia, que era a solução alternativa que eu ja tinha pensado! Obrigado!

Comment: na segunda alternativa que coloquei, a tag img está fora da tag php, porém está dentro de uma condicional, fazendo com que não apareça a imagem. vale a pena tentar.

Comment: Eu tentei, claro..mas continua la a cruzinha! acho que opto pela primeira opção, nao é perfeita mas por enquanto é o melhor que consigo. Obrigado mais uma vez

Comment: @JoaquimRibeiro então ele não está entrando na condicional de verificação se é nulo, você pode substituir pela verificação de vazio empty($imagem3) ou verificar o que está vindo do banco de dados usando print_r($imagem3), pelo que entendi a imagem está no banco de dados, a imagem também pode estar corrompida lá no banco de dados.

Comment: a imagem nao existe @Hoppy! o que pretendo é que quando nao existe imagem no banco de dados, que nao  seja iniciada a tag img para nao ter aquela cruzinha a aparecer na página

Comment: Faz essa tentativa:  <?php if (!is_null($imagem3) && !empty($imagem3) && isset($imagem3)) { ?>
 <img src="<?php echo $imagem3; ?>" width="75" height="75">
<?php } ?>

Comment: @Hoppy, fiz um var_dump e tal como eu disseo resultado é:
string 'fotografias/' (length=12)

naqueles artigos onde o produto existe, tem 
string 'fotografias/0.51942700 1448971409.jpg' (length=37)

Comment: Editei minha resposta, dá uma olhada.

Comment: continua a aparecer a cruz.. ... ta dificil!

Comment: @Hoppy, sabe me dizer porque nao funciona aquele código da resposta que eu dei abaixo?<?php
 if (empty($imagem3)) {
  $imagem3="fotografias/vazia.jpg";
}
 ?>

Comment: porque $imagem3 não está vazia, segundo o que vc postou no dump. você está preenchendo a variavel $imagem3 com "imagem/" . .... mesmo com o banco de dados com a coluna vazia, ou então você já está gravando no banco de dados com "imagem/"

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
$imagem3 = "caminho/da/imagem/img.png";

 if (file_exists($imagem3)) {
    echo("<img src='".$imagem3."'>");
 }

?>
```

este código vai dar certo!

Comment: pq esse código funciona? poderia explicar?

Comment: Descreva melhor a resposta, está muito superficial